Jetpack Compose Clustering sometimes show default markers
I have a screen that contain a list of custom markers with clustering and works fine. The problem is sometime after open de screen my google maps show my customs markers AND the default markers on the same place.
    @Composable
    fun MapScreen(stepResult: HomeState.StepResult) {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
    )

    stepResult.games.let { games ->
        val items = games.map {
            MapTenant(
                itemPosition = LatLng(it.latLng.latitude, it.latLng.longitude),
                itemTitle = it.name,
                itemSnippet = it.address,
                itemZIndex = 0f,
                item = it
            )
        }

        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        Box {
            TenantMapList(sheetState, items)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GoogleMapClustering(items: List<MapTenant>, onMapSelected: (List<MapTenant>) -> Unit) {
    var cameraState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(items.first().itemPosition, 10f)
    }

    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 32.dp),
        cameraPositionState = cameraState
    ) {
        CustomUiClustering(items = items, onMapSelected = {
            onMapSelected(it)
        }, onItemSelected = {
            onMapSelected(listOf(it))
        })
    }
}

@OptIn(MapsComposeExperimentalApi::class)
@Composable
private fun CustomUiClustering(
    items: List<MapTenant>,
    onMapSelected: (List<MapTenant>) -> Unit,
    onItemSelected: (MapTenant) -> Unit
) {
    Clustering(items = items,
        onClusterClick = {
            onMapSelected(it.items.toList())
            false
        }, onClusterItemClick = {
            onItemSelected(it)
            true
        },
        clusterContent = { cluster ->
            CircleContent(
                modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
                text = "%,d".format(cluster.size),
            )
        },
        clusterItemContent = {
            CircleContent(
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
                text = "",
            )
        })
}

@Composable
private fun CircleContent(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Surface(
        modifier,
        shape = CircleShape,
        color = ComplementaryPopUp,
        contentColor = Color.White,
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, defaultGradient)
    ) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Text(
                text, fontSize = 16.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Black, textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TenantMapList(
    sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    items: List<MapTenant>,
) {
    var selectedTenants by remember { mutableStateOf<List<MapTenant>>(emptyList()) }

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
        sheetBackgroundColor = ComplementaryPopUp,
        scrimColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.50f),
        sheetContent = {
            TenantsList(Modifier.wrapContentHeight(), selectedTenants)
        }) {

        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        GoogleMapClustering(items) {
            selectedTenants = it
            scope.launch {
                sheetState.show()
            }
        }
    }
}

Is just random, sometimes when screen is open first time, sometimes when screen is open after 5 times.

You can try filing it as an issue on https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues
